# @Ionic/vue - ERROR in ./node_modules/vue/macros.d.ts while using $ref/$computed

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3, typescript-eslint

**Getting the following error in an Ionic/vue application**:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/vue/macros.d.ts

Code used in components:

```
import { $computed } from "vue/macros";

const x = $computed(() => {
  //code
})

const x = $ref<SomeType>({} as SomeType)
```

Versions:

- "@ionic/vue": "^6.0.0",
- "vue": "^3.2.21",
- "eslint": "^8.4.1",
- "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.2.0",

*Anyone have the same issue and solved it?*

Related:

- https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4499